# Eclipselink JPA criteria format select date

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm developing a web app with Spring 4 MVC and EclipseLink with MySQL. I'm currently stucked with a criteria query to get results with a date field. I have the following code:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

    Root<SsiCheque> fromSsiCheque = query.from(SsiCheque.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if(parameters.containsKey("cheNumero")){
        System.out.println("Param " + parameters.get("cheNumero"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(fromSsiCheque.<String>get("cheNumero"), "%" + parameters.get("cheNumero") + "%"));
    }
    if(parameters.containsKey("cheFechas")){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String[] fechas = parameters.get("cheFechas").split(" - ");
        try {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(fromSsiCheque.<Date>get("cheFecha"), formatter.parse(fechas[0]), formatter.parse(fechas[1])));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(parameters.containsKey("cheReceptor")){
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(fromSsiCheque.<String>get("cheReceptor"), "%" + parameters.get("cheReceptor") + "%" ));
    }

    query.multiselect(fromSsiCheque.get("cheId"), fromSsiCheque.get("cheNumero"), 
            fromSsiCheque.get("cheReceptor"), fromSsiCheque.get("cheMonto"), 
            criteriaBuilder.function("DATE_FORMAT",
                    String.class, fromSsiCheque.<Date>get("cheFecha"),
                    criteriaBuilder.literal("'%d/%m/%Y'")).alias("cheFecha"), fromSsiCheque.get("cheConcepto"))
    .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

    TypedQuery<Tuple> typed = entityManager().createQuery(query);
```

The problem is in the multiselect section where I'm defining a date to be returned and formatted in dd/MM/yyyy with MySQL function **DATE_FORMAT**:

```
                criteriaBuilder.function("DATE_FORMAT",
                        String.class, fromSsiCheque.<Date>get("cheFecha"),
                        criteriaBuilder.literal("'%d/%m/%Y'")).alias("cheFecha")
```

In some posts say the function is called **TO_CHAR** but it seems to be part of Oracle Database API.

The strange thing here is that I'm not getting errors (maybe I need to change logging level) but is not working.

Also I set the persistence.xml to show the generated sql and is as follows:

```
SELECT che_id, che_numero, che_receptor, che_monto, DATE_FORMAT(che_fecha, ?), che_concepto FROM ssi_cheque WHERE che_numero LIKE ?
    bind => [%d/%m/%Y, %12%]
```

**What Am I missing in my criteria query to show dates formatted?**

Thanks

**UPDATE**

What I am getting from the database is 1416895200000 (the date field in milliseconds I guess).

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what you are getting back?  What does the database return if you execute the SQL directly?

Comment: I updated the question with the return result. Thanks

Comment: And what does it return if you just return che_fecha without the DATE_FORMAT function?  It should return a java date object that you can format as you wish.

Comment: If I use with DATE_FORMAT function, I get an error with no trace and without the function I'm getting the date in seconds (416895200000) thanks.